# HTML table data transfer into MS Excel?

Tags: php, html, excel, html-table, transfer

I have a report which is created by PHP getting data from mysql and display in HTML table cells now I just created a button at the bottom of table Transfer in Excel when user click on this button then html data completely transfer in MS Excel.

So how can I do this if anybody have some code, script etc please give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the excellent PHP library [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There's a lot of how-to on the web. Like : http://www.blrf.net/howto/46_PHP__How_to_write_excel_files_with_PHP_.html

Answer (score 1):

you can simply export the data in CSV format, which Excel can import.

Comment: how can i do this i dont know nothing about it?

Comment: CSV is just a comma-separated list like `"value1","value2","value3"` each line will be a row in excel